# PHP code not send form to my email

Tags: php, html, email

Hello I am trying to make my own website for my company. I made a HMTL form and I made some PHP code to make it look better on a page then what it is being sent to me with HTML. My problem is that the PHP is not sending anything to my email.
I removed the POST info from the HTML and most of what is printed.

```
<?php  
$email_from = '$email';
$email_subject = "WWW Form Submission";
$email_body = "Below is the result of your feedback form.  It was submitted by
($email) on $Time\n";



$to = "Email@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: your code has too many errors

Comment: and variables don't get parsed in single quotes

Comment: I'm sure your PHP error logs are telling a compelling tale about this code when it executes.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the quotes prombles. And what is the PHP error logs, I am using notepad. I'm not a computer person.